# one class two onclick functions on one item, can someone help me please

Tags: javascript, html

i cant get the LcloseNav to work.

heres my code i used.the KclosNav work in this code but the LcoseNav does not, seperately they work but joined seems im doing something wrong here, please help with this.thank you.

```
<div id="KmySidenav" class="Ksidenav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Kclosebtn" onclick="KcloseNav();LcloseNav()">&times</a>
</div>
```

Comment: [Works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/czmjdq6s/), the problem is elsewhere. Add more relevant code or this question will get closed soon.

Comment: Have you checked for errors? Does return one of the mentioned functions a false value?

Comment: Add the code for those functions. the issue might be in there

Answer (score 2):

Hi Gareth you should have a function that call both KcloseNav and LcloseNav

then your html should be something like this:

```
 <div id="KmySidenav" class="Ksidenav">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="Kclosebtn" onclick="closeNavs()">&times</a>
 </div>

<script>
    function closeNavs() {
      KcloseNav();
      LcloseNav();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener)

I would do it this way - Change `<a>` to a button.

```
<div id="KmySidenav" class="Ksidenav">
     <button type="button" class="Kclosebtn">&times</button> 
</div>
```

Add event listener

```
document.querySelector('.Kclosebtn').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 KcloseNav();
 LcloseNav();
});
```

Here's explanation:
We are using `querySelector` to get `.Kclosebtn` button. Next, we are adding `click` eventListener. And when someone clicks on it, it will invoke `KcloseNav()` and `LcloseNav()` functions